# Speeding up a self-join in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, optimization, self-join

I have a table with ~2.8 million rows, 3 columns.  Each row represents a marketing-touch from the company and has "customer_id", "marketing_type", and "week_num"  There is an index on "customer_id" and another index on "marketing_type"

An example of the data:

```
72, catalog,  7
72, email,    3
99, catalog, 13
82, catalog,  7
```

I need a list of all customer_id's that had an email, but didn't have a catalog.  (there are other types of marketing, and there are customer_id's that didn't get anything)

**First try:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT cust_id
FROM marketing_campaign
WHERE marketing_type = 'email'
AND cust_id NOT IN (
 SELECT cust_id
 FROM marketing_campagin
 WHERE marketing_type = 'catalog'
 )
;
```

*this query takes 30+ minutes to run*

---

**Second Try:**

```
SELECT m1.cust_id 
FROM marketing_campaign m1
LEFT OUTER JOIN marketing_campaign m2 
  ON m1.cust_id = m2.cust_id 
 AND m2.MARKETING_TYPE = 'catalog'
WHERE m1.MARKETING_TYPE = 'email'
 AND m2.cust_id IS NULL
;
```

*This query executes in 3.8 seconds, but fetches for 30+ minutes.*

---

**Third Try:**

```
SELECT distinct cust_id
FROM   marketing_campaign a
WHERE  MARKETING_TYPE = 'email'
  AND  NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT 'X'
           FROM   marketing_campaign b
           WHERE  a.cust_id = b.cust_id
           AND    MARKETING_TYPE = 'catalog' 
           )
ORDER BY cust_id
;
```

*This query also executes in <5 seconds, but then fetches for 20+ minutes.*

---

**Can anyone suggest an alternative?**

Comment: I suppose you have indexes set properly...and your Query Cache/Buffer Pool set to the appropriate size to handle this data set??

Answer (score 2):

Don't overlook composite indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE marketing_campaign ADD KEY (marketing_type, cust_id);
```

Then use query #2.

Also make sure you have tuned your buffers large enough for the index to reside in RAM.